# Input Data from a Select File using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, importerror

I work at a bank and we regularly receive quarterly Data from Nasdaq Smart about market abuse. I have been assigned with the task of creating a macro to summarize this data to be able to visualize market abuse over longer timelines.

So far I am able to manually select which workbook I am interested in and then the part of the workbook I want to import gets automatically selected.

The problem I have run into is that it wont input the selected data into the new file. If I can trust the compiler, than the issue is that the range function isn't supported in this case.

Private Sub CommandButton23_Click()

```
Dim wkbCrntWorkBook As Workbook
Dim wkbSourceBook As Workbook
Dim rngSourceRange As Range
Dim rngDestination As Range
Dim bottomCell As Range
Dim rngTemp As Range
Set wkbCrntWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Excel 97-2003", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsa , *.xls"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show
    If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
        Workbooks.Open .SelectedItems(1)
        Set wkbSourceBook = ActiveWorkbook
        Set bottomCell = wkbSourceBook.Sheets("par_ACCOUNT").Cells.Find(what:="Account by Type")
        Set rngTemp = wkbSourceBook.Sheets("par_ACCOUNT").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
            If Not rngTemp Is Nothing Then
              wkbSourceBook.Sheets("par_ACCOUNT").Range(bottomCell, rngTemp.Offset(0, 65)).Select
            End If
        wkbCrntWorkBook.Activate
        Set rngDestination = wkbCrntWorkBook.Range("A1")
        Selection.Copy rngDestination
        rngDestination.CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.AutoFit
        wkbSourceBook.Close False
    End If
End With
```

End Sub

Thanks everybody ahead of time for your help. This is my first time working with VBA and Stackoverflow, so any kind of help is welcome.

Comment: `Set rngDestination = wkbCrntWorkBook.Range("A1")` - you are not specifying a sheet.

Comment: You should not use `.Select` in any case. Also its better to use `ThisWorkbook` instead of `ActiveWorkbook`. After your selection you switch WBs so this will probably cause your error when you try to copy.

Comment: @UGB thanks a lot for the help. For future reference, why shouldn't I use selection in any case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem might be caused by selecting a range before activating a different workbook, causing the selection to fail.

```
       If Not rngTemp Is Nothing Then
          wkbSourceBook.Sheets("par_ACCOUNT").Range(bottomCell, rngTemp.Offset(0, 65)).Select
        End If
    wkbCrntWorkBook.Activate
    Set rngDestination = wkbCrntWorkBook.Range("A1")
    Selection.Copy rngDestination
```

I would avoid using `select` altogether, which can be achieved using a simple range object (that was already declared).

```
       If Not rngTemp Is Nothing Then
          set rngSourceRange = wkbSourceBook.Sheets("par_ACCOUNT").Range(bottomCell, rngTemp.Offset(0, 65))
       End If
    Set rngDestination = wkbCrntWorkBook.sheets(???).Range("A1")
    rngSource.Copy rngDestination
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response. I still get the error message "Runtime error '438' Object does not support this method or property' unfortunately. I wonder if there is a smarter way to organize the worklflow in order to maybe expose the mistake. I am surprised there is still such a big issue after the the range is properly selected and just needs to be copied.

Comment: @FelixSchildorfer did you specify a sheet at the line `Set rngDestination = wkbCrntWorkBook.sheets(???).Range("A1")`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code for anyone working on a similar project.

Private Sub CommandButton23_Click()

```
Dim wkbCrntWorkBook As Workbook
Dim wkbSourceBook As Workbook
Dim rngSourceRange As Range
Dim rngDestination As Range
Dim bottomCell As Range
Dim rngTemp As Range
Set wkbCrntWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Excel 97-2003", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsa , *.xls"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show
    If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
        Workbooks.Open .SelectedItems(1)
        Set wkbSourceBook = ActiveWorkbook
        Set bottomCell = wkbSourceBook.Sheets("par_ACCOUNT").Cells.Find(what:="Account by Type")
        Set rngTemp = wkbSourceBook.Sheets("par_ACCOUNT").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
            If Not rngTemp Is Nothing Then
              Set rngSourceRange = wkbSourceBook.Sheets("par_ACCOUNT").Range(bottomCell, rngTemp.Offset(0, 65))
            End If
        Set rngDestination = wkbCrntWorkBook.Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("A1")
        rngSourceRange.Copy rngDestination
        rngDestination.CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.AutoFit
        wkbSourceBook.Close False
    End If
End With
```

End Sub